# Oval/circular shape of the Jason Davies D3 Word Cloud generator

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using Jason Davies's sample word cloud generator code to create a word cloud. I am able to draw it but the shape of the word cloud I would like is oval/circular. I am aware that there have been questions regarding the circular shape of Jason Davies's word cloud but they all were talking about making changes in the build code function `place()` and were also unanswered. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the oval/circular shape modifying the following code:

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var layout = cloud()
    .size([500, 500])
    .words([
      "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
      "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
      return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90, test: "haha"};
    }))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw);

layout.start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
      .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
      .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
      .style("font-family", "Impact")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

In the readme of Jason Davies's Github, there is a mention of `spiral`for word positioning and I am unable to understand since I am very new to the JavaScript. Does anyone has any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following: `.spiral("archimedean")`

Comment: Could you please add some more information? What does `spiral` do and where would OP have to write this line? Thanks.

Comment: spiral is a property to set the shape of the wordcloud...there are two basic shapes in this ..they are RECTANGLE and ARCHIMEDEAN

Comment: @deHaar You'd call this with `layout.spiral("archimedean")` somewhere before the `.on("end",draw);` bit, as the spiral function exists in d3-cloud.  So, perhaps, put it after `.padding(5)` if you like.